# Running Powershell from telnet session in stream mode

Tags: powershell, ssh, telnet

Is there a way to run powershell in stream mode from a telnet session within the command prompt?

This is what I get:

---

*===============================================================

Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Server.

*===============================================================

C:\Documents and Settings\devipa1>powershell

Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

$env:os

powershell -c { $env:os}
Windows_NT
exit

C:\Documents and Settings\devipa1>

---

Powershell isn't outputted correctly without being in console mode.

I would like to use console mode but the tool I'm using cannot parse ansi characters.

[22;1H[0;10mCopyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.[23;1H[0;10m                                                              [24;1H[24;23H[24;1H[0;10mPS C:\Users\devipat1>[24;23H

Would be very grateful if there was a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the workaround.  I had to run "powershell -File -"

Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.3790]
(C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\devipa1>powershell -File -

PS C:\Documents and Settings\devipa1> $env:os

Windows_NT

PS C:\Documents and Settings\devipa1> exit

C:\Documents and Settings\devipa1>exit

Shell process terminated, closing connection.
Connection to 172.16.189.129 closed.

Solution found here.
https://fogbugz.bitvise.com/default.asp?WinSSHD.1.18244